# Packaging / Running Vert.x (3.x) Application

Tags: vert.x

I have started to implement a Vert.x application as follows:-

1. Exposes business API's through REST services.
2. REST services delegates the request (asynchronously) to next level which is my Service layer.
3. Service layer then interacts with either MySQL database (using executeBlocking()) or MongDB (using MongoClient) for all it's data needs.

Basically a multi-tier application. My source code is structured as follows:-

1. There is one Maven Java project containing the REST and Service Vert.x verticles.
2. There is another Maven Java project containing the database access implementations. Here I am using Spring / Hibernate / JPA.

My requirement is to run this Vert.x application in HA mode. I am stuck here as to how to package I tried the Fat Jar option. But I am unable to find ways on how to launch multiple verticles.

Any suggestion / assistance will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you package your different modules is of a less importance than basically how your application modules communicates, i.e. how your RESTful front services talk to your delegable services, and how the later communicates with your backend services. There is no clue in this situation, as you *Vert.x* emphasis microservices architecture and we can adopt yours goes in that style.

If you have followed the *Vert.x* spirit (I'll assume you did since I cannot see any source code), then your verticles should be self contained and can be all deployed from, say a **deployment verticel**, that will bootstrap the whole application.

From this point of view, your verticles can land in the same *fat* jar alltogether, and when running your application you should be only starting a single aforementioned *verticle* that will load and setup the different verticles, something like below:

```
~$ vertx run com.somepackage.MyDeploymentVerticle
```